# Distinguishing transverse and longitudinal from wave equation

Tags: waves

Can we distinguish if a general wave or disturbance $f$ (not necessarily electromagnetic) which satisfies the wave equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2}
= \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2} \equiv \nabla^2 f
\end{equation}
is transverse or longitudinal?

Comment: What do you mean by "in general"? Do you want the identification to be based entirely on the nature of the wave function?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Yes. Maybe I myself am not very sure at this point, but is there a way to extract information about the mode of propagation by looking at the wave equation? If not, how else could we distinguish them?

Comment: I think that you have to consider a wave equation in dimension>1 since the notions of longitudinal and transverse usually refer to vectors.

Comment: @Urgje yes, the full equation is actually three dimensional. If there is three dimensional, how would I distinguish it then?

Comment: No, because the wave equation applies to both longitudinal and transverse waves. Physical context should tell you what $f$ is supposed to be.

Comment: @Javier, are there transverse waves of scalar quantities?

Comment: A slinky can have transverse or longitudinal waves--both scalar.

Answer (score 2):

According to Ibach and Lüth (8th ed.), section 11.4:

Transverse waves obey $\nabla\times f≠0$ and $\nabla f=0$.

Longitudinal waves obey $\nabla\times f=0$ and $\nabla f≠0$.

Comment: This implies that $f$ is a vector. That might not be the case.